# GTK data binding

Tags: python, data-binding, gtk, pygtk

Is there any mechanism for data binding (like in WPF) in GTK (to be precise pygtk) ?
I want to get rid of this ugly code:

```
 def set_foo(self,txt):
    return self.gtkBuilder.get_object("foo").set_text(txt)

 def get_foo(self):
    return self.gtkBuilder.get_object("foo").get_text()
```

and have something similar to this:

```
self.foo = "text"
self.gtkBuilder.get_object("foo").data_bind(self.foo)
```

If I changed `self.foo`, my gtk object `"foo"` would change too and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

You could use properties:

```
class X(object):
    ...
    def _make_property(name):
        def getter(self):
            return self.gtkBuilder.get_object(name).get_text()
        def setter(self, text):
            return self.gtkBuilder.get_object(name).set_text(text)
        return property(getter, setter)

    foo = _make_property("foo")
```

This is completely unrelated to GTK.  It's just the Python way to define properties.

Answer (score 0):

GTK Widgets use GObject properties which [can be bound](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/GBinding.html). Unfortunately this probably won't be added to the deprecated PyGTK. The newer GObject-Introspection has it, but only in broken form unless you have a very recent version.

For now you are better off rolling your own like Sven, or using a library like [gtkmvc](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pygtkmvc/wiki).